# multiselect jqgrid: id column formatter is integer but selarrrow returns array of strings

Tags: jqgrid, jqgrid-formatter

I have my column model as  -

```
colModel: [{name:'id',index:'id', width:200, formatter:'integer', hidden:true},
```

I see that the json data from the server is returned with the value of the id field as an integer, but `$('#list').getGridParam('selarrrow')` gives me an array of strings. Why?
Is there anyway I can get it as an array of integers?

Thanks,

Comment: The value returned from the server would be a string, it might be formatted as an integer, but it is a string.  What operation are you trying to do to the data that an array of strings can't be operated on as integers?

Comment: @Mark, like I've mentioned, the data from the server is an integer. I've verified that. I basically just send the array to the server to perform a database operation on records whose primary keys are the ids. I'm trying to avoid iterating on the list and cast them to integers. A list of integers is all I need on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `formatter: "integer"` means just inserting thousand separators (`,` or `.` from the language file which you use).

The `id` attribute of any HTML elements (inclusive `<tr>` which represent the row of the grid) contains no other data types as string. jqGrid interpret `id` always as strings too.

Comment: I just inspected the HTML of the grid and I see what you are saying. I didn't realize that the formatter was just for the UI formatting. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: @ksrini: You are welcome! You can use [parseInt](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp) to convert string with integer to integer: `var i = parseInt("123", 10);`. Is the problem is solved now?

Comment: Yes, it is solved. I use python on the server side, so I did a `id_list = map(int, id_list)`